missing attribute in android java library binding
I have recently created new android java library binding project in my MAUI 8 solution for use a java .aar library in my MAUI project.
I have been added .aar file into Jars/ directory and configured .csproj file like this :
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidLibrary Include="Jars\tapsell-plus-sdk-android-2.2.8.aar" Bind="false" />
  </ItemGroup>

but after i cleaned and building the project, I got this errors :
    APT2260 attribute aspect_style (aka TapsellPlusBinding.TapsellPlusBinding:aspect_style) not found.
    APT2260 attribute aspect_ratio (aka TapsellPlusBinding.TapsellPlusBinding:aspect_ratio) not found.

this is my first android java library binding project. so I dont know about what going on.
can anybody help me for fixing this issue
EDIT 1 :
I have been created new solution and android java binding project and then I referenced the .aar file into it. I just needs this package and its haven't dependency to install. also lower versions of this package is working and I have this issue just in the latest version.

Try to add all required dependencies of the Android library as NuGet packages to the binding project.

@JianweiSun-MSFT i have been created new solution and android java binding project and then i referenced the .aar file into it. i just needs this package and its haven't dependency to install. also lower versions of this package is working and i have this issue just in the latest version.

Well, you can follow up this issue: Error APT2260 when reference to Binding project #8919 to report your situation.
